# How does a person who is not following meta keep informed of changes?

Tags: discussion, notifications

**Background:**

This happened to me just today.
I posted a comment about a question being subjective (and hence might be better off being a wiki) and had someone tell me (rightly) that there is no such thing as community wiki anymore (EDIT: Atleast in regards to the checkbox option that used to be there for the person posting the question)!

That, of course, made me feel a bit silly!!

Now, be that as it were, being a member of SO, i would like to be somehow kept updated of any such changes that take place. However, from a practical perspective, i do not find the time to really monitor or track such discussion on meta to be able to be in the know automatically.

**Question:**

Is there any mechanism (short of following meta religiously) as to how a person can be kept abreast of such operational / conventional changes to SO and how it operates (be it a result of meta discussions or otherwise)?

Comment: NB: Community Wiki still exists - it is just that questions cannot be made community wiki by end users anymore. (You have to flag the question for moderator attention). You can still answer a question by making it CW, and CW questions do not magically poof out of existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

devinb started [**this**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow) list of feature changes to the sites (including dates and links to the requests) which are kept up to date by other users.  Favorite it.  :)

Comment: +1 That does help greatly! More power to devinb! Now if only i could get informed about any changes to this post when i visit SO instead of having to visit meta, that would just be the icing on the cake..Any ideas on that front?

Comment: @InSane: Subscribing to the [rss feed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/59445) seems the way to go then.  Though I don't know how it behaves since there are no new answers, just updates to the one.  (I should add that though devinb started it, he's not the only maintainer but a number of people, thank them too ;))

Comment: Exactly the thought i had in mind. Subscribed to it anyways. Now waiting and watching till the next update to see if that works. Oh..its a community answer...more power to them all!! :-)